# Link Dinâmico? E como implementar?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json

Eu não sei o nome dessa técnica, sou estudante, mas as vezes eu vejo no canto inferior esquerdo do chrome o link completo tipo...

http://www.bla.com/.../o-video-game-legal.html

Aí de repente muda para:

http://www.bla.com/violencia/o-video-game-legal.html

Eu sou novo em web e perdoem minha ignorância caso seja algo simples.
Eu queria saber o que é esse: /.../
 e também como eu façopro link ficar organizado: /o-video-game-legal.html

Comment: Está confuso .. afinal, vc quer saber como gerar links ou como funciona a barra de status do browser?
No Google Chrome, os links são exibidos de forma resumida e após alguns segundos é exibido o link completo na barra de status.. é apenas um recurso visual do browser, nada a ver com php, javascript, etc..

Comment: O navegador apenas oculta o miolo da URL, deixando o domínio e o final. Quando você mantém o ponteiro sobre o link ele aparece inteiro. Pode mudar nas opções avançadas do navegador.

Comment: Eu ja vi isso antes e não é nada do que vocês falaram.  E eu sei que é relacionado com Back-end, mas eu só sei php então não adianta nada eu não colocar uma tag e receber a resposta em java. Eu vou considerar a resposta inútil. E não faz sentido nenhum OCULTAR porque o facebook tem links GIGANTESCOS e não acontece isso.

Comment: `canto inferior esquerdo do chrome o link` você está falando da forma como o navegador mostra a URL. Isso aparece no seu site?

Comment: Não, eu estou falando do /.../ que se transforma em /categoria/ normalmente eu vejo se transformar em categoria, mas também ja vi se transformar em /321312/ provavelmente ID ou Codigo de alguma coisa. E não é coisa do navegador, tenho certeza. Provavelmente é um Json, por ser algo "variavel" .

Comment: Não percebeu que só acontece com links grandes?

Comment: @AsuraKhan Estou fechando a pergunta por falta de clareza. Repare que você recebeu três respostas já, e cada uma fala de uma coisa diferente. Fica claro que as pessoas não estão entendendo o que você quer exatamente. Você poderia esclarecer, de preferência editando a pergunta? Se precisar de algum esclarecimento da minha parte, é só me chamar com `@bfavaretto` aqui nos comentários.

Comment: `/../` não se *transforma* para `/321312/`. O que acontece é que em alguns sistemas o caminho pode ser reduzido para `/../` apenas para visualização, mas no `href`, `src`, etc. o caminho continua completo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que entendi o que quis dizer. Fiz uma solução em PHP, mas dá para usar a mesma lógica em outra linguagem. Esses `/../` significam que a URL sofre um encurtamento, e o conteúdo removido está onde os pontos estão. Exemplo:

http://um-site-qualquer.com/categorias/tecnologia/titulo-da-pagina

Poderia ser encurtado para http://um-site-qualquer.com/../titulo-da-pagina. Isso reduz o tamanho da "frase" mas mesmo assim mantém o endereço original ao clicar nela. É possível reproduzir o mesmo efeito.

Eu criei uma expressão regular que pega o conteúdo entre a primeira barra e a última barra da URL (`/../`). Após isso simplesmente usei o `preg_match_all` para pegar o resultado do REGEX e criei uma nova variável com o novo endereço. Com os dois endereços em mãos (o original e o encurtado), podemos criar uma tag `<a>` do jeito que você quer. Veja o código:

```
<?php

// URL de exemplo
$url = "http://www.exemplo.com/categorias/jogos/veja-as-incriveis-novidades-de-2015";

// Aplica o Regex na URL
preg_match_all('/[\da-z\.-]+\/(.+)\//', $url, $url_match);

// Pega o resultado do Regex
$new_url = str_replace($url_match[1][0], "..", $url);

// Cria um elemento <a> com nossas URLs.
$element = "<a href='$url'>$new_url</a>";

// Imprime o resultado na página
echo $element;
```

Veja funcionando no Ideone: https://ideone.com/NEV6j6

---

Em uma página rodando o PHP, o resultado será esse (perceba que ao clicar no link o endereço original que é aberto):

```html
<a href='http://www.exemplo.com/categorias/jogos/veja-as-incriveis-novidades-de-2015'>http://www.exemplo.com/../veja-as-incriveis-novidades-de-2015</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

O browser apenas diminui o link para ficar melhor legível ao usuário, mas o link original não muda, é apenas uma forma de melhorar a legibilidade.